# Bit manipulation in nested MACRO leads to `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` why?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to manipulate certain bit( bit 1) using the following nested macros, but I am running into the error `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

My code is as follows

```
#define CONTROL1 (*((unsigned int volatile *) 0x00AA))
#define CONTROL2 (*((unsigned int volatile *) 0x00BB))

#define XC_PIPE(pipe) (unsigned int volatile *)( (pipe) == 0 ?  (CONTROL1) : (CONTROL2) )
    
#define XC_ENABLE(pipe) ( ( XC_PIPE(pipe) ) |= (1<<(1)))

#define XC_DISABLE(pipe) ( ( XC_PIPE(pipe) ) &= ~(1<<(1)))

#define XC_MODULE_TOGGLE(on,pipe) ( (on) == true ?  (XC_DISABLE(pipe)) : (XC_ENABLE(pipe)) )
```

and I call it like this

```
XC_MODULE_TOGGLE(false,0);
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the necessary indirection in

```
#define XC_ENABLE(pipe) ( ( XC_PIPE(pipe) ) |= (1<<(1)))
#define XC_DISABLE(pipe) ( ( XC_PIPE(pipe) ) &= ~(1<<(1)))
```

Please change to

```
#define XC_ENABLE(pipe) ( *( XC_PIPE(pipe) ) |= (1<<(1)))
#define XC_DISABLE(pipe) ( *( XC_PIPE(pipe) ) &= ~(1<<(1)))
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work at all. `XC_PIPE` should be an lvalue but its definition is incorrect.

Comment: for your answer to work, you must also change `CONTROL1` and `CONTROL2` to remove the initial `*` dereferencing operator, which changes the semantics of these macros that may be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `XC_PIPE()` is flawed: the cast `(unsigned int volatile *)` is incorrect as both `CONTROL1` and `CONTROL2` already dereference the absolute address. To ensure that `XC_PIPE` can be use as an L-value, you should write it this way:

```
#define XC_PIPE(pipe) (*((pipe) == 0 ? &(CONTROL1) : &(CONTROL2)))
```

You can remove some redundant parentheses too and prevent warnings about unused values by making `XC_ENABLE()` and `XC_DISABLE()` `void` expressions:

```
#define CONTROL1  (*(unsigned int volatile *)0x00AA)
#define CONTROL2  (*(unsigned int volatile *)0x00BB)

#define XC_PIPE(pipe) (*((pipe) == 0 ? &(CONTROL1) : &(CONTROL2)))

#define XC_ENABLE(pipe)  (void)(XC_PIPE(pipe) |= (1 << 1))
#define XC_DISABLE(pipe) (void)(XC_PIPE(pipe) &= ~(1 << 1))

#define XC_MODULE_TOGGLE(on, pipe)  ((on) ? XC_DISABLE(pipe) : XC_ENABLE(pipe))
```

Comment: I am sorry but the compiler gives the 'lvalue' message for this code.

Comment: @WeatherVane: this is a subtile difference between C and C++: ternary expressions are not L-values in C but can be in C++ if the second and third expressions are compatible L-values themselves. Answer amended.

Comment: From C compiler.

Comment: I think the best *solution* would be to use a (inline) function instead of macros. The macros are decision making, and the result would be clarity and less error-prone.

Comment: @chqrlie one question, the result `XC_MODULE_TOGGLE(false,0);` would return some value? Or it will return a value and set the register? I ask this because compiling your solution shown this warning when I use the macro ->`warning: value computed is not used`

Comment: @ndarkness: both `XC_ENABLE()` and `XC_DISABLE()` evaluate to values, and so does `XC_MODULE_TOGGLE()`. I amended the answer to prevent such warnings.